# Content Types from Hub not showing up in sub site

Tags: 2010, content-type, site-collection, content-type-hub

I have the following web application

**MainWeb**

And within that application i can 2 site collections as follows

**/**

**/sites/home**

I have created a Content Type Hub on my main site collection ("**/**") and completed all the necessary steps to publish my content types. These content types are appearing in other web applications but **NOT** in my sub site (**/sites/home**).

Is this something to do with my site being a sub site of the publishing content type site?

S

Answer (score 1):

Your sub sites will have the content types.

Make sure that you have created the content types, and the hub, on the root site. You know that you are on the root site because if you go to site settings, you will see the "Site Collection Administration".

Really the only possibility is that the hub is not coming from the root site of the site collection (I don't even know if that's possible?).

The answer the question:
Is this something to do with my site being a sub site of the publishing content type site?

No.

Additionally, content types will always flow downward to sub sites, but if a content type is created on a sub site, it will not flow to sister subsites or upward to the root site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still face this problem, but I just had the same problem and the solution might be of use to others as well.

It appears to be due to the content type being created in an Enlish site (/sites/contenttypehub), and being succesfully published to (and showing up in) our English team site (/), but *not* to the Dutch subsite /vaktechniek. After I changed this subsites language to English, the new content type immediately appeared in the content types.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I have been facing a similar issue for the past 2 hours and I figured I would post my answer here. If you are creating your content types in your root site i.e. (Mainweb/) you must ensure that you are configuring MMS within central administration. Then you must activate "content type syndication hub" of the site collection you want to use those content types in i.e. (Mainweb/sites/home) once I did this, those content types appeared in all my site collections.